# Differences between the automatic calculation of the mesh thickness and its direct measurement with scale applied

Tags: mesh

I have noticed a difference between the calculation of the thickness of a solid using the related Mesh Analysis tool and the  thickness value of the same solid measured with the digital ruler, as you can see in the picture here below.

What is the reason for this difference? As far as I can understand and verify with printed products, the effective thickness of the solid is the one measured with the ruler; do you agree with that?

[image: Thickness value measured with the Mesh Analysis tool and digital ruler. Sometimes happens this - the thickness values calculated though the edge length and through the Mesh Analysis do not match]

[image: Measuring with the ruler and with the automatic tool for edges shall return the same result if the right projection is applied]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your title states that the scale was applied, but your screenshot shows otherwise. Could you clarify?

Comment: Please refer to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304771/differences-between-the-automatic-calculation-of-the-mesh-thickness-and-its-dire. Applying the scale has not solved the issue.

Comment: Hey. Please don't scatter information about your issue across different posts, it is much harder to follow and keep track of. Also please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, use the [Edit] button above, and include information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Show a screenshot of your object scale applied, and the modifier stack showing how different modifiers may be affecting your object. Otherwise diagnosing by blind guesses is an unnecessary trial and error process

Comment: I have already written you that the scale factors are blocked in this example. Please read the second post about this subject and watch the second image attached to it.

Comment: Applying all the transformations helped me correct the measurements of the edges; in some cases, this command is also sufficient to correct the mesh analysis, but not always, as you can see above.

Comment: Sorry, if you don't know the answer, it is not my fault. Please study this aspect and try to answer it. In the meantime, I have found another solution; I cannot lose time with it.

Comment: You can see from the picture above that the scale has been correctly applied, otherwise you could not even see the correct linear measurement of the thickness.

Comment: I'd advise you edit your question and add to it all relevant information, including screenshots of your object properties, modifiers and other data. Also if necessary share a simplified file through [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com). "*You can see from the picture above that the scale has been correctly applied*" the image shows nothing of the kind

Comment: Sir, please remind that I do not need to lose time. If the scale were not uniform, you could not see the same measurement of thickness in meters all around the outer surface.

Comment: Under the object transform (not shown) scale should be 1,1,1.  If not, ctrl+a and apply scale.  Uniformity of the mesh in world space really has nothing to do with it, the scale is a *transform* property and will be applied to all measurements that arise from calculations on the mesh.  The ruler is separate and is measuring world space distances.

Comment: Dear Allen, I thank you for your contribution but please note that the automatic measurement of the length of an edge and the measurement of the same with the ruler agree perfectly if you project the image on a plane, for example on the X-Z plane, which is the most useful in this case.

Comment: Sorry for the question: have you ever tried to print with a 3D printer an object designed in Blender? It does not seem so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the reason for this difference?

If you examine the **Thickness** *Mesh Analysis* tool, you will see that it include a samples slider. This means that it uses samples to calculate the thickness. Sadly, it has a hard limit of 32 samples which doesn't produce very accurate results. However, I think the reason the values are not accurate is because it seems to cast rays in different directions and averages the thickness. If one or more of these rays end up somewhat parallel to the surface, they will cause the measurement to be inflated. Maybe, the minimum of the samples should be chosen, but please note this is just my guess. I didn't check the source code.

[image: Thickness Mesh Analysis tool]

On the other hand, the measurements obtained with the *Measure* tool are typically correctly placed by the user to measure the minimum thickness which tends to be along the surface normal. And this explains why the tool does the sampling approach, because the minimum thickness is not always going to be along the normal, so the tool has to look around, in a sense.

> As far as I can understand and verify with printed products, the effective thickness of the solid is the one measured with the ruler; do you agree with that?

I agree. Whatever you measure is definitely real and should match what you measure digitally with the *Measure* tool as long as both measurements are carried out along the same direction at the same spot.

I typically use the *Analysis Tools* to figure out possible problematic areas, and then manually verify that they are okay with the *Measure* tool. The *Thickness Analysis Tool* tends to falsely mark edges of printed pieces.

Comment: Dear Mr A, Thank you for your answer; I sincerely appreciate your explanation. Should you need any help, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: You're welcome!